# What exactly is dyno hour on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'm really confused by Heroku pricing.

**What exactly is dyno hour?**

Heroku is giving 750 dyno hours for free. For example my regular request will take 100ms to process.

So, this request will take **100ms** from **750 free dyno hours**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From documentation:

"Heroku usage is computed from wall-clock time, not CPU time. This means that usage accumulates over time as long as dynos are enabled, regardless of traffic or activity."
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/usage-and-billing#computing-usage

750 hrs is enough to cover any single dyno for an entire month.  Essentially "non-production" apps are free in that regard. (unless you have another non-web process running, like celery etc)

Comment: So number of visitors and served requests doesn't matter at all, right? They can't influence how much dyno hours I'll need (I know that I can scale up to achieve better performance)? 

When I'll be running simple website 750 hours will be enough, as you said. And if I decide to scale to 2 dynos - I'll have 375 free hours for each dyno. When this free hours are consumed I'll be billed for more hours to the end of the month. For example 24 hours * 31 days = 744 hours. I have 375 free hours so I'll be billed for 369 hours, right?

Comment: That all sounds right.  Billing happens at the end of the month.  For 2 dynos, the math works out to be (24*31*2)-750 = 738hrs billed (so yes, 369hrs for each dyno).  Keep in mind that an app with a single dyno "goes to sleep" after a period of inactivity (minutes, not hours).  It takes about 10-60 seconds (depends on your app) for the dyno to boot up after it's been asleep.  It's not really suitable for production apps, but you can find workaround. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-sleeping

Comment: Are the 750 free hours for the lifetime of the app, or does the counter reset every month (similar to how Google App Engine resets it's free quotas every time unit)?

Comment: It's 750 free hours per app per month.
"Heroku automatically credits each app with 750 free dyno-hours per month, which are clearly identified on your invoice."

Comment: @Jody, what would you recommend for production apps?  I have a simple web app that's part of my portfolio, but hosting in on heroku has that unpleasant "waking up dyno" part which I feel might annoy viewers like recruiters or hiring managers.

Comment: The wakeup thing sucks.  If you have something pinging it all the time, it's basically always awake...but that seems against the spirit.  You could crank up to 2 and pay the $30/mo while you're job hunting.  or you could spend countless hours getting your app on an EC2 micro for ~$10 month (assuming you're not a big linux person).