# What is dynos in Heroku in plain english?

Tags: heroku

What exactly is Dynos? if im not mistaken , it is an isolated virtual linux container. What really confuses me right now are

1) Is Dynos equivalent to process or server?

2) 1 Dyno can handle how many users?

3) How do i explain what is Dyno to a normal people

4) Pricing for performance application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a single Heroku Web Dyno?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462439/what-exactly-is-a-single-heroku-web-dyno)

Comment: See also [What exactly is a dyno hour on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753173/what-exactly-is-dyno-hour-on-heroku?rq=1)